# Applying set operation on list of dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary, set

My list contains same dictionaries multiple times like

Like

```
[ {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}, {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}]
```

When I apply set operation on this to make it distinct, it gives

```
TypeError: unhashable type: 'dict'
```

What is correct way to make this sort of list item distinct?

Answer (score 5):

Dictionaries are mutable objects so can't be stored in a set. You could convert the dictionaries to an immutable object that represents the same data; after applying a `set()` operation to these you can then convert back to dictionaries:

```
unique = [dict(t) for t in set(tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in l)]
```

This converts each dictionary to a *sorted* tuple containing all key-value pairs; this assumes that the *values* in the dictionary are immutable as well however.

Sorting is required because it is possible to produce two dictionaries that have the same key-value pairs but list these in a different order due to hash collisions; two keys can map to the same hash-table slot but the one that's inserted first will win:

```
>>> {'bar': 42, 'baz': 81} == {'baz': 81, 'bar': 42}
True
>>> list({'bar': 42, 'baz': 81}) == list({'baz': 81, 'bar': 42})  # compare keys in order
False
```

Answer (score 2):

A straightforward way can be to convert each `dict` into string and use a `set` on it and then convert each string back to `dict`

```
>>> import ast
>>> l=[ {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}, {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}]
>>> l
[{'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}, {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}]
>>> [ast.literal_eval(i) for i in set(map(str, l))]
[{'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}]
>>>
```

Another approach for different ordering where in we convert each `dict` to a `tuple`:

```
>>> l=[ {'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}, {'gram': '1', 'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD'}]
>>> set([tuple(d.items()) for d in l])
{(('name', 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD'), ('gram', '1'))}
>>> [dict(i) for i in set([tuple(sorted(d.items())) for d in l])]
[{'name': 'ZYLOG SYSTEMS LTD', 'gram': '1'}]
>>>
```

Comment: Depending on how the presence of hash collisions and how the input dictionaries where created, the exact ordering of the keys in the string representation can easily *differ* even for dictionaries that are actually equal.

Comment: Try your method with `[{'bar': 42, 'baz': 81}, {'baz': 81, 'bar': 42}]`, for example.